# Second monitor not detected - ASUS G15-GA502

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I've already tried several solutions, but I think the main problem is that I don't know what the source of the problem is.

I am new to Ubuntu, I had an older Acer (i5-7300HQ and GTX 1050) which ran Ubuntu flawlessly. Now I upgraded to an ASUS G15 (R7-4800HS and RTX 2060 Max-Q) and when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot I had several problems.

1. Couldn't install because it froze every time during install.
2. After every reboot the screen was black and there was only a blinking cursor.
3. Cannot use second monitor because it doesn't recognize it.

I could solve the first two problems by setting `nomodeset` thanks to [Coldfish's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38782#38782)

To solve the third problem I've tried many solutions like :

- Installing other Nvidia drivers (435, 440, 450, etc.).
- Installing Radeon Vega drivers.
- Installing newer version of kernel (I wasn't able to boot after).
- etc...

In the last few days I reinstalled Ubuntu for a dozen times, and I am desperate. I would like to use my PC to run Visual Studio Code for school and that's all. I could do it without an external screen, but it really isn't the sacrifice I would like to make.

I can give you any information you need to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and dual boot with Win10 for only four days. Ubuntu 20.04 works ok, but install it on this laptop is a bit hard :D. Installation crashes and finished it in recovery mode.

The VEGA Renoir card runs correctly with a secondary display on HDMI after I install kernel 5.9. I do not tests any version of the kernel 5.8.

In my case, the NVIDIA card not work on the internal or external panel with any noveau or NVIDIA drivers.